# ¿Cómo obtener la URL de un objeto recién subido a un bucket de AWS S3 desde una función lambda?

Tags: nodejs, aws, amazon-s3

He visto que se puede añadir "triggers" a funciones lambda para que se ejecuten, por ejemplo, cuando un archivo es subido a un bucket en S3.

¿Sería posible que en esta función, se pudiese obtener el link del mismo objeto que ha "disparado" la función?

Por ejemplo, cuando subo una imagen a un bucket, se genera siempre una dirección url para poder visualizar esta imagen en línea. Lo que estaría buscando es cómo obtener este link url en la misma función lambda para luego insertarlo inmediatamente en una base de datos (DynamoDB). Estoy usando Node.js

Hasta ahora he probado con lo siguiente

```js
// dependencies
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const util = require('util');
const sharp = require('sharp');

// get reference to S3 client
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

function response( message) {
  return message
}
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-2'});


exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    
    // Read options from the event parameter.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    
    let scanningParameters = {
        Key: {
            "site": srcBucket
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set photos = :photos",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":photos": [
             "urldelobjectorecienSubido"
             ]
        },
        TableName: 'Galleries'
    }
    
    return docClient
    .update(scanningParameters)
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }})

    

};
```

En vez de la ULR del objeto subido al bucket, he intentando, sin éxito, sacar el nombre del bucket en

```
`Key: {
        "site": srcBucket
    },`
```

Aunque eso también lo necesitaría, en principio el objetivo principal sería sacar la URL del objeto recién subido al bucket e insertarla aquí:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
     ":photos": [
         "urldelobjetorecienSubido"
         ]
    },
```

El código lo he obtenido de aquí: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtuve la solución, este código siguiente es el que me sirvió:

Lo que hacemos si queremos obtener el link completo para la imagen, será obtener la llave del objeto con `event.Records[0].s3.object.key;` 
La string que resulte de ahí la podemos concatenar a nuestro link global de S3, que podemos obtener simplemente con `https://nuestronombredelbucket.s3.laregiondondelotenemos.amazonaws.com/`

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const util = require('util');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-2'});
const response = (message) => { return message }

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    
    const bucketUrl = "https://nuestronombredelbucket.s3.laregiondondelotenemos.amazonaws.com/"
    // Juntamos la url de arriba junto a la key y obtenedremos el link para la imagen
    const srcPhoto = bucketUrl.concat(srcBucket)
    
    let scanningParameters = {
        Key: {
            "site": "site_id"
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set photos = :photos",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":photos": [
             srcPhoto
             ]
        },
        TableName: 'Galleries'
    }
    
    return docClient
    .update(scanningParameters)
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }})
    
};
```

Es importante que nuestra función también tenga permisos para usar CloudWatch. De lo contrario no funcionará.